# IIS 7 And Failover Partner

Tags: iis, iis-7, connection-string, mirroring

I'm trying to migrate a few asp.net applications from iis 6 to iis 7 and I've run into a few snags along the one.  I can't find any documentation for the issue I'm seeing and wanted to see if someone else has encountered the same problem.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 db mirroring on my databases.  In the connection strings of my application I have specified the Failover Partner, which caused no issues in iis 6.  Now after moving to iis 7, the failover partner keyword in the connection string is causing my application to timeout when trying to access the database.  The application works fine when I remove the failover partner keyword from the connection string.

Has anyone run into this issue?  Is this expected behavior or some sort of bug?

Any information anyone could provide me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar issue for ado.net 2.0 applications, but that was fixed quite some time ago.  Do you have .net 3.5 installed? If not , install it, as it includes service packs for 2.0 and 3.0.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912151 The connection may time out before the first try to connect to the failover partner server when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 mirrored database by using an ADO.NET 2.0-based application

Comment: I am running .net 3.5 sp1 on my server.

Comment: Can you post your connection string, masking out anything confidential?

Comment: Here's the connection string I'm using. connectionString="Data Source=Server;Failover Partner=FailoverServer;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=****;Password=****;" Nothing really out of the ordinary. All the servers are specified by ip, and the db servers are not named instances.